# Flutter mobile device image screen to large

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile

I am currently using android studio flutter to test my prototype I manage to run my template successfully onto the mobile device however template is to large and I dont know how to make the template smaller so that it would fit onto the screen

when you select this link you can be able to see what it looks like:

[mobile device image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deB5P.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32,47);

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Image.network("https://i.stack.imgur.com/deB5P.png", fit: Boxfit.fill),
    )
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    // This is the theme of your application.
    //
    // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
    // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
    // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
    // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
    // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
    // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
    // is not restarted.
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use box constraints by giving width and height properties. If you want your app to be responsive you can use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html). And for image you can use fit property like `Image.asset("image", fit: BoxFit.cover),` to know more about constants of BoxFit refer [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: YourImage(),
    );
  }
}


class YourImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you I am new to using android studio I wanted to ask if I put that code you have given me where do I have to put it specifically do I have to put it within "pubspec.yaml"? :)

Comment: No, for box constraints you don't have to do anything with pubspec.yaml.

Comment: do I write that particular code onto "main.dart" :)

Comment: Can you please provide some more information like some code snippet you have used? It will help to know exact what problem you are facing.

Comment: for that image you saw I written "home: Question1()," (Question1" is the image you saw within the mobile device) that code I written that within "main.dart" after I written it I ran the program the image I posted here you saw of the mobile device and the template being to large thats what I saw when I ran the program for the first time

Comment: Inside Question1() class have you placed image or you are creating the view using some widgets?? If you could paste your code then it would be great and easy for the community to help you.

Comment: ok I will post it now what you will see is all of the "main.dart" code including what I have written the only think I have written is "home.Question1()" the rest I did not write as the code has already been provided/given to me when I downloaded android studio

Comment: Is Question1() containing image?? can you please provide what's inside Question1() ??

Comment: question 1 is what I named the image itself the photo which I have posted for you to see is the actual image and I named that image question 1

Comment: See i have posted the code, Try using it. Just replace with you image. And if you are  using asset image then use Image.asset()

Comment: I have not ran the program yet I have put the new version of the code onto here can you double check to see what I have written is ok and if there is any changes you want me to make let me know :)

Comment: I also wanted to ask you do you have gmail/email address for me to be able to communicate with you better instead of us communicating here :)

Comment: this link you have given me tanharpatel.tech did not work the second link tanharpatel.wixsite.com/techyhub  worked I noticed when i opened the second link on the bottom right hand side a small popup box it said "lets chat" would you respond through there by any chance :)

Comment: Connect here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/tanharpatel/

Comment: thank you I have connected with you if you see the name Hanna who has connected to you that is me my name is Hanna if you can can you be able to message me first please on linkedin :)

Comment: I have also sent you a message through your blog specifically "Let's Chat" box :)